# Scalar form of magnitude of vector quadratic

Tags: vectors

$\def\b#1{\mathbf#1}$
I know that $\|\b{b}t + \b{c}\|$ can be written as $\sqrt{ (\b{b} \cdot \b{b}) t^2 + 2(\b{b} \cdot \b{c})t + \b{c} \cdot \b{c}}$

Is there a similar expression for $\|\b{a}t^2 + \b{b}t + \b{c}\|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose so. Suck it up and do it: $$\begin{align}  \|{\bf a}t^2+{\bf b}t+{\bf c}\|^2 &= ({\bf a}t^2+{\bf b}t+{\bf c})\cdot({\bf a}t^2+{\bf b}t+{\bf c}) \\ &= ({\bf a}\cdot{\bf a})t^4 + ({\bf b}\cdot{\bf b})t^2+({\bf c}\cdot{\bf c}) + 2(({\bf a}\cdot{\bf b})t^3 + ({\bf a}\cdot{\bf c})t^2+({\bf b}\cdot{\bf c})t),\end{align}$$ and take roots.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{({\bf a} \cdot {\bf a})\ t^4 + 2 ({\bf a} \cdot {\bf b})\ t^3 + 2 ({\bf a} \cdot {\bf c})\ t^2 + ({\bf b} \cdot {\bf b})\ t^2 + 2 ({\bf b} \cdot {\bf c})\ t + ({\bf c} \cdot {\bf c})}$

Comment: Thanks, I think you missed the a.c term.

Answer (score 0):

By definition the magnitude of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is $\| \mathbf{v} \| = \sqrt{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}}$. Therefore, by definition:

$$\|\mathbf{a}t^2 + \mathbf{b}t + \mathbf{c}\| = \sqrt{(\mathbf{a}t^2 + \mathbf{b}t + \mathbf{c}) \cdot (\mathbf{a}t^2 + \mathbf{b}t + \mathbf{c})}$$

The rest of the math should be simple from there using the distributive property.